# Directly download the output file to client desktop

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am processing a video file using ffmpeg, in AWS lambda. My file size is 1gb. I don't want to store the processed file in /tmp folder (or efs).

Is there a way I can directly download the output file to the user's desktop, from AWS lambda?

Comment: You want the lambda to initiate a file transfer to someone's desktop, or send the file as a response to the desktop client's request?

Comment: On desktop client's request, ffmpeg will fetch a file from S3 (using a url), process it, and return the processed file to that desktop.